# Problem handling correctly strip_tag/substr in preview and expanded post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to show a 4 line context all without tags and the rest of it only with `<br>` tag.

What I though for the first part is the following that runs correctly as I want:

1. I `strip_tags` description and save it to `$post`
2. Get only 320 chars and save it to `$preview`

code

```
$post = strip_tags($entry->description);   
$preview = mb_substr($post, 0, 320, "UTF-8");
```

My problem is with the expanded preview, as I said it needs to start where `$preview` stopped and show only `<br>` tags

What I did is this but it is not working correctly

```
$expanded = mb_substr($entry->description, 321, 9999999, "UTF-8");
$expanded = strip_tags($expanded, '<br>');
```

The reason that is not working correctly is because when I `echo $preview.$expanded;` when the `$preview` ends, it usually continues with a break tag and then the text.

```
this is the `$preview`
and here goes `$expanded` that it does not continues from where `$preview` ended, usually with a half tag
p1BHvrI/AAAAAAAABm0/kMxU6nXgXSo/s320/20110921_125449.JPG" width="320" />
here goes the rest of the `$expanded`
```

My question is how `$expanded` starts correctly right after `$preview` ends without any "broken tags" as above?

**UPDATE**

as said because this is a tricky situation, maybe a possible solution is to replace `$preview` (320 chars) with `$expanded` (full content).

This is my expanding mechanism http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to know how to handle this. Like you say there is a good chance that you will end up with a broken tag doing it the way you are above, because if your `mb_substr` ends up in the middle of a tag, `strip_tags()` won't remove it correctly.

Without seeing exactly how the mechanics of the expansion work at the client side I can't say for sure, but I think you would want to do something more like this:

```
$preview = htmlspecialchars(mb_substr(strip_tags($entry->description), 0, 320, "UTF-8"));
$description = strip_tags($entry->description,'<br>');
```

...and when you do the expansion, *replace* `$preview` with `$description`, rather than *appending* `$description` description to the end of `$preview`.

There is something else to consider here though - you should probably pass *both* strings through `htmlspecialchars()` and if you do that with `$description`, the `<>` around the line breaks will be escaped as well, where you don't want them to be. I can;t come up with an effective solution to this part, it probably needs some kind of horrible regex...

Comment: +1 for the idea of replacing the content. Yes this may be the solution because as you said indeed, it's very tricky. This is a working fiddle of the expansion http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/19/ I am updating my question also.

Comment: I don't do jQuery so I can't give you a working example but I would say what you want to do is have one `<div>` with preview, default `display: block` and one with full description, default `display: none` and when you click the expand link just swap the `display:` over between the two. Also, in your example you have two `<div>`s with the same ID `thepost`, which is asking for trouble...

Comment: Thanks again. I will leave it open until I accept your answer because there must be a PHP way (I don't think so though).